# Sending data from STM32F401 MCU to ESP8266 and getting response from ESP8266 to MCU

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4, esp8266

am working on an STM32f401 Nucleo board and ESP8266 wifi module. I am using Eclipse gcc-arm tool chain and cubeMx to generate code. I can transfer and receive data perfectly with USART/UART DMA.

Now I am stuck with ESP8266. I cannot send data from MCU to ESP and I'm not getting response from ESP to MCU. I already tested the ESP module communication, I can connect TO THE wifi with AT commands through USB and can also receive data in web via socket connection.

I configured USART1_TX/USART1_RX with PA9/PA10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be obvious that this is unanswerable without specifics of the code and the failure

Answer (score 1):

I worked with esp8266 on stm32f100 and all was fine. Please check baund rate and power supply. The esp8266 can consume up to 250 mA. If you have connected it to 3.3V on the board, it is possible insufficient current.

Comment: Which model did you use? I'm trying to get the data sheet for esp8266 12 f and I'm not getting anything Relavant. I only got a document that specifies pin diagram, nothing else.

Comment: I worked with ESP8266-01

Comment: Where did you get the reference manual from?

Comment: i am also working with ESP8266-01 and using basic AT commands.